# Showing the rref of an augmented matrix having a particular form.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. I’m looking at the following augmented matrix:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    a & -b & -c & -d & 0 \\
    b & a & -d & c & 0 \\
    c & d & a & -b & 0 \\
    d & -c & b & a & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I suspect that its rref would always have the form:

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Is there a simple indication as to why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if at least one variable is nonzero. But I guess it depends on what you mean by "simple".

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%7B%7Ba%2C-b%2C-c%2C-d%7D%2C%7Bb%2Ca%2C-d%2Cc%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%2Ca%2C-b%7D%2C%7Bd%2C-c%2Cb%2Ca%7D%7D) gives the determinant of your coefficient matrix as
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2,
$$
which will be nonzero as long as at least one of $a,b,c,d$ is nonzero. This means that the coefficient matrix is invertible and so the RREF is as you say.